# TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. In GNU Radio

Tags: python-3.x, gnuradio

I've Been Recently Learning GNU Radio using python, and when making a ASCII to float Symbols Hierarchical Block modulation, I encountered this error :

```
Qt GUI: Could not restore geometry: restoreGeometry(self, geometry: Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alper\Documents\GNU Radio\asc2sym_bf.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\alper\Documents\GNU Radio\asc2sym_bf.py", line 179, in main
    tb = top_block_cls(a_bpsym=options.a_bpsym, b_eds=options.b_eds, c_pol=options.c_pol, d_inv=options.d_inv, e_true_asc=options.e_true_asc)
  File "C:\Users\alper\Documents\GNU Radio\asc2sym_bf.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.blocks_packed_to_unpacked_xx_0 = blocks.packed_to_unpacked_bb(1, 1)
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. gnuradio.blocks.blocks_python.packed_to_unpacked_bb(bits_per_chunk: int, endianness: gnuradio.gr.gr_python.endianness_t)

Invoked with: 1, 1
```

And I tried Debugging it, But Not Successfull :(, So Please Help me, Here's The Code That I've Written:

```
from packaging.version import Version as StrictVersion
from PyQt5 import Qt
from gnuradio import qtgui
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import digital
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from gnuradio.fft import window
import sys
import signal
from PyQt5 import Qt
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from gnuradio.eng_arg import eng_float, intx
from gnuradio import eng_notation

class asc2sym_bf(gr.top_block, Qt.QWidget):

    def \__init_\_(self, a_bpsym=1, b_eds=1, c_pol=1, d_inv=0, e_true_asc=0):
        gr.top_block.\__init_\_(self, "ASCII to Float Symbols", catch_exceptions=True)
        Qt.QWidget.\__init_\_(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("ASCII to Float Symbols")
        qtgui.util.check_set_qss()
        try:
            self.setWindowIcon(Qt.QIcon.fromTheme('gnuradio-grc'))
        except BaseException as exc:
            print(f"Qt GUI: Could not set Icon: {str(exc)}", file=sys.stderr)
        self.top_scroll_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.top_scroll_layout)
        self.top_scroll = Qt.QScrollArea()
        self.top_scroll.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.top_scroll_layout.addWidget(self.top_scroll)
        self.top_scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.top_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.top_scroll.setWidget(self.top_widget)
        self.top_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.top_widget)
        self.top_grid_layout = Qt.QGridLayout()
        self.top_layout.addLayout(self.top_grid_layout)
    
        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "asc2sym_bf")
    
        try:
            if StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) \< StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
                self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry").toByteArray())
            else:
                self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry"))
        except BaseException as exc:
            print(f"Qt GUI: Could not restore geometry: {str(exc)}", file=sys.stderr)
    
        ##################################################
        # Parameters
        ##################################################
        self.a_bpsym = a_bpsym
        self.b_eds = b_eds
        self.c_pol = c_pol
        self.d_inv = d_inv
        self.e_true_asc = e_true_asc
    
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.M = M = 2\*\*a_bpsym
    
        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
    
        self.digital_map_bb_0 = digital.map_bb(d_inv\*list(2\*\*8-1-i for i in range(2\*\*8))+(1-d_inv)\*list(range(2\*\*8)))
        self.blocks_packed_to_unpacked_xx_0 = blocks.packed_to_unpacked_bb(1, 1)
        self.blocks_char_to_float_0 = blocks.char_to_float(1, (c_pol\*0.5+(1-c_pol)\*1))
        self.blocks_and_const_xx_0 = blocks.and_const_bb(255)
        self.blocks_add_const_vxx_0 = blocks.add_const_ff((-c_pol\*(M-1)+(1-c_pol)\*0))
    
    
        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_const_vxx_0, 0), (self, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_and_const_xx_0, 0), (self.digital_map_bb_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_char_to_float_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_const_vxx_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_packed_to_unpacked_xx_0, 0), (self.blocks_char_to_float_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.digital_map_bb_0, 0), (self.blocks_packed_to_unpacked_xx_0, 0))
        self.connect((self, 0), (self.blocks_and_const_xx_0, 0))
    
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "asc2sym_bf")
        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())
        self.stop()
        self.wait()
    
        event.accept()
    
    def get_a_bpsym(self):
        return self.a_bpsym
    
    def set_a_bpsym(self, a_bpsym):
        self.a_bpsym = a_bpsym
        self.set_M(2\*\*self.a_bpsym)
    
    def get_b_eds(self):
        return self.b_eds
    
    def set_b_eds(self, b_eds):
        self.b_eds = b_eds
    
    def get_c_pol(self):
        return self.c_pol
    
    def set_c_pol(self, c_pol):
        self.c_pol = c_pol
        self.blocks_add_const_vxx_0.set_k((-self.c_pol\*(self.M-1)+(1-self.c_pol)\*0))
        self.blocks_char_to_float_0.set_scale((self.c_pol\*0.5+(1-self.c_pol)\*1))
    
    def get_d_inv(self):
        return self.d_inv
    
    def set_d_inv(self, d_inv):
        self.d_inv = d_inv
    
    def get_e_true_asc(self):
        return self.e_true_asc
    
    def set_e_true_asc(self, e_true_asc):
        self.e_true_asc = e_true_asc
    
    def get_M(self):
        return self.M
    
    def set_M(self, M):
        self.M = M
        self.blocks_add_const_vxx_0.set_k((-self.c_pol\*(self.M-1)+(1-self.c_pol)\*0))

def argument_parser():
    description = 'Conversion from ASCII (bytes) to M-ary symbols'
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=description)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--a-bpsym", dest="a_bpsym", type=intx, default=1,
        help="Set Bits per Symbol \[default=%(default)r\]")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--b-eds", dest="b_eds", type=intx, default=1,
        help="Set LSB First \[default=%(default)r\]")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--c-pol", dest="c_pol", type=intx, default=1,
        help="Set Polar \[default=%(default)r\]")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--d-inv", dest="d_inv", type=intx, default=0,
        help="Set Invert Bits \[default=%(default)r\]")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--e-true-asc", dest="e_true_asc", type=intx, default=0,
        help="Set 7-Bit ASCII \[default=%(default)r\]")
    return parser

def main(top_block_cls=asc2sym_bf, options=None):
    if options is None:
        options = argument_parser().parse_args()

    if StrictVersion("4.5.0") \<= StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) \< StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
        style = gr.prefs().get_string('qtgui', 'style', 'raster')
        Qt.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem(style)
    qapp = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    tb = top_block_cls(a_bpsym=options.a_bpsym, b_eds=options.b_eds, c_pol=options.c_pol, d_inv=options.d_inv, e_true_asc=options.e_true_asc)
    
    tb.start()
    
    tb.show()
    
    def sig_handler(sig=None, frame=None):
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()
    
        Qt.QApplication.quit()
    
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)
    
    timer = Qt.QTimer()
    timer.start(500)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: None)
    
    qapp.exec\_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am pretty sure the code is correct but cannot make sense out of the error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you use `1` as "endianness" argument. But I don't know what that is supposed to mean, and neither does GNU Radio!

You'll have to use one of the two valid values, `gr.endianess_t.GR_MSB_FIRST` or `….GR_LSB_FIRST`.